# Best practices for using AWS Cognito with AWS SNS and expiring push tokens

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, amazon-sns

I have an application (Java Spring backend + iOS/Android native frontends) that uses AWS Cognito for Authentication and AWS SNS for sending push notifications to devices. The client apps currently pass the device-specific push tokens (FCM, APNS) to the backend, which informs SNS.

We are struggling to figure out the best way to deal with users logging out or simply not using the mobile apps for a while, and expiring/disabling those push tokens. Cognito does not appear to have any sort of trigger or notification for when a token expires or a user signs out. This leads to users still receiving app pushes after logging out or when their access/refresh tokens have expired.

I am looking for suggestions and best practices on what to do here. Some options we entertained are to inform our backend in a separate call, move all device management there, or even façade all of Cognito behind our own backend calls, but maybe there’s better ways.

Answer (score 0):

last month they released [refresh token revocation](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/06/amazon-cognito-now-supports-targeted-sign-out-through-refresh-token-revocation/), is a way to revoke a refresh token and all access tokens that were previously issued by that refresh token become invalid

this is enabled for new user pools but i believe in your case, you need to manually enable it in (e.g. you created the user pool before the feature was released)

> Cognito does not appear to have any sort of trigger or notification for when a token expires or a user signs out.

you are correct here, but, in case you use [`GlobalSignOut`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_GlobalSignOut.html) API in your App, you could track it [via CloudTrail or EventBridge](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/logging-using-cloudtrail.html) and trigger a lambda do to something with the event

> Some options we entertained are to inform our backend in a separate call, move all device management there, or even façade all of Cognito behind our own backend calls

i worked in both scenarios, while the façade gives a lot of flexibility, if you are offering social login, it is annoying to setup the whole oidc flow,

in my projects i usually use cognito as an user directory to generate unique user ids and integrate with other aws services.

like DynamoDB with item-level control based on the Cognito User Id, which is handy:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_dynamodb_items.html
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/building-fine-grained-authorization-using-amazon-cognito-user-pools-groups/

making it easy to create and manage user devices token etc

> but maybe there’s better ways.

hope never dies